# How to compute $f(n)\%M$ , where $f(n)=1^n*2^{n-1}*3^{n-2}*4^{n-3}*\dots*n^1$ and $M=10^9+7$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am new to modular and computer programming for it, today in one of the contest I have got this problem tried by going with the brute force method but not able to solve in the required time limit.

This is what I was trying to do,
$$f(3) = 1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3$$
$$f(4) = 1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot4$$
$$f(5) = 1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot4\cdot4\cdot5$$

But I was unable to solve as $n$ can take value upto $10^9$.

So I want to know that if some better algorithm/ method exist for solving this type of problem in mathematics.

Thank You, your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the link to this problem

Comment: @NikhilBalwani [codechef: biteration](https://www.codechef.com/BIT22019/problems/MATHL)

Comment: I'm sure the contest problems aren't supposed to be solvable by brute force. They require you to have some background (looking through existing solutions, online tutorials, etc.). With attempts to (get and) apply it, even failed ones, you're welcome here. Otherwise... I don't see a *result* of any potential help. (Still, a hint: find a relation between $f(n)$ and $f(n-1)$. And go a step further.)

Comment: $10^9+7$ is a prime. $f(n)=\prod_{k=1}^n k!$.

Comment: Please explain your "brute force" method.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ,brute force technique is to run a for loop according to given pattern. Eg. if n=3 then f(n) = 1.1.1.2.2.3 , so in a loop we will multiply 1 three times, 2 two times and 3 one time. similarly for n=n , 1 n times, 2 (n-1) times and so own.

Comment: @PraveenKumarRana: do you mean only taking the modulo in the end ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, no since I am solving this problem in C++ , I need to take modulo whenever the number is greater then 10e9+7 i will be taking modulo. I can use property of Modulo here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read some of the [submissions on codechef](https://www.codechef.com/BIT22019/problems/MATHL) and you will find some algorithms. The simplest direct approach is to use the facts that:

$$(a\times b)\%c=[(a\%c)\times(b\%c)]\%c$$

$$(a^b)\%c=\begin{cases}1,&b=0\\ [(a^2)\%c]^{b/2}\%c,&2~|~b\\ [a\times(a^b)]\%c,&\text{else}\end{cases}$$

Further optimizations can be done e.g. the result is almost always zero as long as $n$ is greater than or equal to the largest prime factor of $M$, but for most purposes, the above and a suitable fast language (namely C++ as you can see by the submissions) can get the job done.

[Quick and dirty python program](https://tio.run/##fY9BDsIgFET3nGI2JqW2Kl2acIQeghZqSSwQxGhPX/mkxp0sGMK8@Zkf1jR717VhDetml@BjQlRO@2XTZsLitXmHSjUYGoz8yqBwkBgZonlAQjC8Zns3GLIFO2HAAR1kduhjp@iuKUnBjJwluvxQ2VI/I5r0jI5gxhylSo0TiXWpEg3EhQ5n/V@Xheh16Tb5CAvrCL4ZYtxR0BI7UaT@LmmL3WbpeW7U0yAaTRTftg8).

The intended approach was most likely to use the fact that

$$f(n)=\prod_{k=1}^nk!$$

as pointed out by [Yves Daoust](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3363676/how-to-compute-fn-m-where-fn-1n2n-13n-24n-3-dotsn1-an/3363719#comment6922613_3363676), from which one can do this with a simple for loop. [python code](https://tio.run/##fY07DsMwDEN3nYJLgThNi7pjgR4hhwiSfjREFgwvPr1juZ6rhQT4KGpO3yD3i2bNhXcNMSEusoW9CJ7dXk1Y0uAn@Judo/lvShrDVglP72VNPxMiGCzW@rwMlrN3D0JHm4xo/AkzoTebjBi40i2ov23NeFfKAQ).